# How to rescale value to a specific range?

Tags: r, range, cumsum, rescale

I'm trying to rescale a dataset of Rdata comprised between 0.17 and 0.00002589 to a range between 0 and 1. I would like the cumulative frequence to be equal to 1.

I tried to use the function rescale (from scales package) :

```
library(scales)

t <-rescale(df, to = c(0,1)) #data go from [0.00002589:0.17] to [0.53:0.00004914]

cumsum(t)= 4.24...
```

How do I correct my data in order to have cumsum equal to 1 ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add

```
t <- t / sum(t)
```

For example:

```
set.seed(42)
df <- rnorm(n = 10, 1)
t <- scales::rescale(df, to = c(0,1))
t <- t / sum(t)
cumsum(t)


#[1] 0.1740706 0.1740706 0.2575087 0.3652035 0.4523411 0.4935800
# [7] 0.6802913 0.7225612 0.9548573 1.0000000
```